# Maps out of cohomology groups (associating group elements to cohomology classes)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be a topological space, and let the second cohomology group of $X$ with coefficients in integers, $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$, be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. For example, take $X$ to be the sphere $S^2$. I am trying to understand how I can define a map $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathbb{Z}$ and a map $\mathbb{Z} \to H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$. In other words, how can I extract an integer from an element $[\alpha] \in H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$? After figuring out this, I want to go for the general case; if $G$ be a commutative group and $H^2(X,G)$ be isomorphic to some group $H$, how can I associate an element $h$ in $H$ to an element $[b] \in H^2(X,G)$? Is there any good reference for studying about this?

Comment: One can understand a group encountered in the wild by understanding a [presentation for that group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group).

Comment: It is not really clear what you want to do.

Comment: If you know $H^2(X,Z)$ is isomorphic to $Z$ then there is an isomorphism $\phi:H^2(X,Z)\to Z$, and then every morphism $H^2(X,Z)\to Z$ is of the form $x\in H^2(X,Z)\mapsto k\phi(x)\in Z$ for some choice of $k$ in $Z$. In other words, these are all the ways you can *extract an integer* from elements of $H ^2(X,Z)$.